# How to transform fields in abinitio so as to have common schema in output file?

Tags: ab-initio

I have 6 files in which 2 files have 53 fields and rest have 49 fields.
I want an output having a common schema of 53 fields THROUGH AB INITIO such that when I process files having 43 fields it comes as blank in the output schema by itself.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by simply using the **REFORMAT** component.
Attach the proper record format to each Input File components (in your case, containing either 49 or 53 fields).

Then you can attach the ones with 49 fields directly to a **GATHER** component. The files having a lesser number of fields you can just attach them to the input of a **REFORMAT** and connect the **REFORMAT** output to the **GATHER** component.

Then in the Transform, you just connect corresponding input/output fields and fill with a constant value ("",0,etc...) the 4 missing ones.